# Porting web-app for a tablet

Tags: simulator, tablet, tablet-pc

My web app is written in Java with front-end in JS. I want to port to tablet and other touch mobile devices. Developing a native API is ofcourse an option but I would prefer making the old app work on tablet.

I know I would need to make some changes in UI for the touch interface and I am willing to do it.

So My question is: A**re there tablet Simulators available on which I can try my app and see where it breaks on such device.**

**What would be the best approach to proceed on this?**

thanks in advance!

Comment: Theoretically, the onclick event would be the only reliable one, as there is no keyboard and such devices usually send the messages in the wrong order.

Answer (score 0):

Tablets use various OS's and, thus, different API's, supported features, etc...  For iPad, for imstance, XCode provides a simulator.  I read somewhere that the BB tablet coming out will have a simulator for dev as well.